# Defer Reordering a Rapidly Updating Knockout Array Element

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm rapidly updating the contents of a sorted Knockout array, and found that I cannot actually interact with the rapidly updating items. Here's a greatly simplified example:

```
<script type="text/html" id="link-template">
    <a data-bind="text: name" href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
</script>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'link-template', foreach: links }"></ul>

<script>
    var Link = function(name) {
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
    };

    var Vm = function() {
        this.links = ko.observableArray();
    };

    var model = new Vm();
    model.links.push(new Link('link1'));
    model.links.push(new Link('link2'));
    ko.applyBindings(model);

    setInterval(function() {
        var len = model.links().length;
        var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        var removed = model.links.splice(target, 1);
        model.links.unshift(removed[0]);
    }, 1000 / 30);
</script>
```

My intent is to order the most recently updated links first, mocked out here with random updates. Direct updates, `model.links()[0].name('...')`, allow me to click the link on the item, but I also want to support reordering.

Trying to interact with the rapidly updating array is a pretty bad user experience so I think best the solution would be to defer reordering an element in the list until the user is no longer hovering over it, decoupling the displayed array from the data array more. The other list elements should still be reordered around the fixed, active element.

Is there any easy way to do this in Knockout? Are there any existing plugins that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed based on the observableArray of links. When the mouse is in the `ul`, the computed returns a copy made at the time the hover started; when the mouse is not in the `ul`, the computed returns the current list of links.

```js
    var Link = function(name) {
      this.name = ko.observable(name);
    };

    var allowReorder = ko.observable(true);

    var model = {
      links: ko.observableArray([
        new Link('link1'),
        new Link('link2')
      ]),
      allowReorder: ko.observable(true)
    };

    var copyOfLinks;
    model.allowReorder.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      if (!newValue) {
        copyOfLinks = model.links.slice(0);
      }
    });

    model.computedLinks = ko.computed(function() {
      if (model.allowReorder()) {
        return model.links()
      } else {
        return copyOfLinks;
      }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(model);

    setInterval(function() {
      var len = model.links().length;
      var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
      var removed = model.links.splice(target, 1);
      model.links.unshift(removed[0]);
    }, 50);
```

```html
<div>Something</div>
<ul data-bind="foreach: computedLinks, event: {mouseover:allowReorder.bind(null, false), mouseout:allowReorder.bind(null, true)}">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="text: name" href="https://stackoverflow.com"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```